# Installed graphics card, which color wires connect

Tags: graphics-card, power-supply, power

I just installed this graphics card, I am unsure of whether to connect the graphics card 3 black and 2 yellow pin to my white plastic power supply pin which has 4 black 2 yellow and 2 red. I am cautious. I wanted to post prior to causing a short circuit or any damage to my power supply or computer - if that outcome is possible in this scenario.

[image]

Comment: you are fine, that will work, you're not going cause a short or damage anything.

Comment: I think it's pretty safe these days to say, if the plugs will fit together, it is correct.